# How to covert number to words in velocity template?

Tags: java, velocity, apache-velocity, velocity-template-language

I am using velocity template, I want to convert number to words, Is there any library present for that?

eg: 99999999 = ninety-nine million nine hundred ninety-nine thousand nine hundred ninety-nine

Comment: If velocity doesn't provide that functionality (which I am sure it does not), you can implement it yourself [and use it in velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35656731/7109162)

Comment: The is definitely no set API for this. You would have to write your own logic for this. At the end of the day, Velocity does support Java-like code, the syntax is bit different. So you can write you own in Velocity.